# function not avaliable after restarting Apache

Tags: perl, path, perl-module

I am fairly new with perl and apache and seem to be having a small problem with my code.

I have 3 files:

**hw.pm**

```
package hw;

sub calc {
    my $num1 = shift;
    my $num2 = shift;
    return $num1 + $num2;
}
1;
```

**startup.pl**

```
use lib qw(path to where hw.pm is located);
1;
```

**hel.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use hw;
use CGI qw(:standard);
print header;

my $ans = calc(5,4);
print $ans;
```

I have no problem restarting apache but when I access hel.pl from the browser I get an error `Can't locate hw.pm in @INC`

Should the startup.pl have already included it in `@INC`? Or am I missing something?

I am using perl v5.10.1 and Apache2 v2.2.16

Comment: where is hw.pm located? in hel.pl you only include `use hw` which assumes that the hw.pm will be located in @INC (normally common modules directory + the directory where the script is run)l perhaps you forgot to incorporate startup.pl

Answer (score 0):

Perl is not finding `hw.pm`.

Try copying this line from startup.pl

```
use lib qw(path to where hw.pm is located);
```

to hel.pl, replacing the "`use hw;`" there. But first make sure the path is correct.

---

> **@INC** - The array @INC contains the list
>   of places to look for Perl scripts to
>   be evaluated by the do EXPR , require
>   , or use constructs. It initially
>   consists of the arguments to any -I
>   command line switches, followed by the
>   default Perl library, probably
>   "/usr/local/lib/perl", followed by
>   ".", to represent the current
>   directory.

Comment: I placed use lib in hel.pl and that seemed to work. My understanding was that if I place it in the startup.pl file which is executed from apache2.conf it will increase in performance?

Comment: @Melvin Sorry, i have no info about that. Did you check the path to startup.pl in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. initially i had this in my apache2.conf:

PerlRequire startup.pl

but after adding this code:

`<Directory /var/www>
   SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
    PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>`

I was able to access my modules from hel.pl

Thanks guys for your help.